# Tabel view width getting change automatically

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi i have a table of size (0,0,200,200) on ipad screen.when i run application it looks ok when i search table it's size get changed automatically and cover all the area on ipad screen.

But i want to be remain fixed in same area (0,0,200,200).

how to fix this bug

following code used regarding search controller

```
if (self.savedSearchTerm)
{
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:self.searchWasActive];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar     SelectedScopeButtonIndex:self.savedScopeButtonIndex];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:savedSearchTerm];

    self.savedSearchTerm = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the tableview's frame is what you want. Try this:

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);
```